# Add unbound combo box to form that can trigger a BeforeUpdate() event?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a datasheet form `ItemsForm` based on table `Items`.  `Items` is one-to-many related to table `StatusHistory`, between `Items.ID` and `StatusHistory.ItemID`.  There is also a `Status` table, with the relationship between `Status.ID` and `StatusHistory.StatusID`.

I want to add a `StatusBox` combo box to `ItemsForm` so that when the user selects a `Status` value from the box and then moves out of the record, which should trigger the `Form_BeforeUpdate()` event, a new entry is added to `StatusHistory` with the `Items.ID` of the currently selected entry.

I've successfully added the `StatusBox` field to the form and populated its list by setting its RowSource with a query of `Status`.  But there are two big problems:

1. I can scroll through the values in the box's list, but after I
   select one, it doesn't show up in the field; the field stays blank.
2. When I select a value in `StatusBox`, and then click onto another
   record, the `Form_BeforeUpdate()` isn't triggered.  It seems that
   `Form_BeforeUpdate()` is only triggered if I modify data in the
   fields from `Items` that the form is based on.  Is there a different event that I should be using here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it as follows:

1. The ID field for `Status` is actually named `StatusID` instead of
   `ID`.  Fixing this allowed me to enter values into the field.
2. I put the code into the `BeforeUpdate()` event for `StatusBox`, viz:

```
Private Sub StatusBox_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

End Sub
```

This means it gets triggered whenever I select an item in the list, rather than when I move to a new record, but for now that's all I need.